# Wait for Observable to complete within an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have the following data structure:

```
export class Repo {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    contributors: Contributor[];
}

export class Contributor {
    id: number;
    login: string;
}
```

I am using `Observable<Repo>` to fetch all repo data but I want to internally call another observable `Observable<Contributor>` to populate all contributors before the outer `Repo` is considered fully emitted. I am not sure how to do this. I have the following code.

```
private repos: Repo[] = [];

getRepos(orgName: string): void {
    const repoBuild: Repo[] = [];
    this.githubService.getRepos(orgName).pipe(
        // this here won't wait for all contributors to be resolved
        map(repo => this.getRepoContributors(orgName, repo))
    ).subscribe(
        repo => repoBuild.push(repo),
        error => {
            this.repos = [];
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => this.repos = repoBuild
    );
}

// fetches contributors data for the repo
private getRepoContributors(orgName: string, repo: Repo): Repo {
    const contributors: Contributor[] = [];
    repo.contributors = contributors;
    this.githubService.getRepoContributors(orgName, repo.name)
        .subscribe(
            contributor => {
                // add to the total collection of contributors for this repo
                contributors.push(contributor);
            },
            error => console.log(error),
            () => repo.contributors = contributors
        );
    return repo;
}
```

I admit that my understanding on `Observable`'s is limited and I have struggled on this for quite few hours. I tried finding something that works for me on StackOverflow but I still could not find a working solution. Any help would be appreciated!

(The code is written in Angular 5)

**Solution:**

I used @joh04667 suggestion below and eventually got it to work. Here is how I did it:

```
getRepos(orgName: string): void {
    const repoBuild: Repo[] = [];
    this.githubService.getRepos(orgName).pipe(
        // mergeMap() replaces `repo` with the result of the observable from `getRepoContributors`
        mergeMap(repo => this.getRepoContributors(orgName, repo))
    ).subscribe(
        repo => repoBuild.push(repo),
        error => {
            this.repos = [];
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => this.repos = repoBuild
    );
}

// fetches contributors data for the repo
private getRepoContributors(orgName: string, repo: Repo): Observable<Repo> {
    repo.contributors = []; // make sure each repo has an empty array of contributors
    return this.githubService.getRepoContributors(orgName, repo.name).pipe(
        // tap() allows us to peek on each contributor and add them to the array of contributors
        tap(contributor => {
            // add to the total collection of contributors for this repo
            repo.contributors.push(contributor);
        }),
        // only picks the last contributor and replaces him/her with the repo
        last(
            () => false,
            () => repo,
            repo
        )
    );
}
```

Here in the last part where I use `last()` I basically tell the `Observable` that even though it will process all values, I am only going to consume the last one. The last one is of type `Contributor` but I replace it with a default value (the `repo`) which allows me to change the return type from `Observable<Contributor>` to `Observable<Repo>` which is exactly what I need for the higher-level Observable.

Comment: have you tried using switchmap or flatmap operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question, and to me this is the 'big step' to really understanding the full power of Observables: higher-order Observables, or Observables that return Observables.

Your situation is perfect for the [`mergeMap / flatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) operator:

```
getRepos(orgName: string): void {
    const repoBuild: Repo[] = [];
    this.githubService.getRepos(orgName).pipe(
        // this will map the emissions of getRepos to getRepoContributors and return a single flattened Observable
        mergeMap(repo => this.getRepoContributors(orgName, repo))
    ).subscribe(
        repo => repoBuild.push(repo),
        error => {
            this.repos = [];
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => this.repos = repoBuild
    );
}
```

`mergeMap` will map emissions of an outer Observable `(getRepos)` to an inner Observable (`getRepoContributors`) and return a new Observable that only emits when the inner Observable completes. In other words, it flattens out values that are passed from one Observable to another into one succinct subscribe-able data stream.

Higher-order Observables can be hard to wrap your head around, but that is really where the true power of Observables lie. I highly recommend checking out some other operators like `switchMap` and `concatMap` on the site I linked as well. Observables can get crazy powerful when used to their fullest extent.

#### EDIT

I misread the original code and thought `getRepoContributors` was returning an Observable. Long work day had me fried. I'll refactor here:

`map` is good for altering the value before merging it with `mergeMap`. The first couple lines of `getRepoContributors` can be done there. Since `mergeMap` needs an Observable returned to it, we can simplify a bit:

```
private repos: Repo[] = [];

getRepos(orgName: string): void {
    const repoBuild: Repo[] = [];
    this.githubService.getRepos(orgName).pipe(
        map(repo => {
            repo.contributors = [];
            return repo;
          }),
        mergeMap(repo => this.githubService.getRepoContributors(orgName, repo.name)),
        map(contributor => {
            repo.contributors.push(contributor)
          })
    ).subscribe(
        repo => repoBuild.push(repo),
        error => {
            this.repos = [];
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => this.repos = repoBuild
    );
}

// don't need second function anymore
```

We can `map` in the stream expecting the value to change in sequential orders with the operator.

Comment: hey @joh04667 thanks for the answer, but I can't get it to work. This is my problem: I need a `repo` to be emitted so that I can pass it to `getRepoContributors` where it uses `repo.name` to fetch the contributors, then I subscribe to `getRepoContributors` to collect all contributors in an array which I assign back to the `repo` once the subscription completes. This approach with `mergeMap` will convert my `Observable<Repo>` to `Observable<Contributor>` so when I subscribe I no longer have access to the repo.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Didn't see you were subscribing to another Observable in the second method instead of returning an Observable. I'll update my answer.